# How to log in Python

Tags: python, delete-file

I have some code that looks at a directory and deletes files older than 60 seconds:

```
import os
import datetime

dir_to_search = '/documents/folderfordeletetest/archive/'
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(dir_to_search):
   for file in filenames:
      curpath = os.path.join(dirpath, file)
      file_modified = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(curpath))
      if datetime.datetime.now() - file_modified > datetime.timedelta(seconds=60):
          os.remove(curpath)
```

How can I log what is being deleted?

Comment: Is there a reason why to a .csv file? Python has a logging module which is being used widely.

Comment: i guess just what i am used to, how could i use the logging module to achieve this ?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-to-a-file

Comment: could that log each file name that is deleted and when ?

Comment: For time see: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#displaying-the-date-time-in-messages For the message you will have to generate the string that you want to log. You have the filename in the variable `file`. So you create a message containing that `file` variable.

Answer (score 1):

So after some research I have found that this is the way to achieve what I am after.

```
import os
import datetime
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='delete.log' ,format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %. 
  (message)s', level=logging.INFO, datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

dir_to_search = '/documents/folderfordeletetest/archive/'
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(dir_to_search):
   for file in filenames:
      curpath = os.path.join(dirpath, file)
      file_modified = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(curpath))
      if datetime.datetime.now() - file_modified > datetime.timedelta(seconds=60):
          os.remove(curpath)
          logging.info(file)
```